# C# - Windows Form - Remove Background color from custom control

Tags: c#, custom-controls, custom-component

- I have a custom rating control and I need to draw stars only with no background Rectangle to use it on any other controls.
- without a background, only the stars.

The drawing code as the following:

```
    using System;
       using System.Windows.Forms;
       using System.Drawing;
       using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
    
       namespace Start_Rate
       {
        public class Rating : System.Windows.Forms.Control
        {
            public Rating()
            {
                SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
                SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
                SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
                SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    
                Width = 120;
                Height = 18;
    
                m_starAreas = new Rectangle[StarCount];
            }
    
            #region Properties
    
            public int LeftMargin
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_leftMargin;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (m_leftMargin != value)
                    {
                        m_leftMargin = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            public int RightMargin
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_rightMargin;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (m_rightMargin != value)
                    {
                        m_rightMargin = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            public int TopMargin
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_topMargin;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (m_topMargin != value)
                    {
                        m_topMargin = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            public int BottomMargin
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_bottomMargin;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (m_bottomMargin != value)
                    {
                        m_bottomMargin = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            public int StarSpacing
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_starSpacing;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (m_starSpacing != value)
                    {
                        m_starSpacing = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            public int StarCount
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_starCount;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (m_starCount != value)
                    {
                        m_starCount = value;
                        m_starAreas = new Rectangle[m_starCount];
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            public bool IsHovering
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_hovering;
                }
            }
    
            public Color OutlineColor
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_outlineColor;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (m_outlineColor != value)
                    {
                        m_outlineColor = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            public Color HoverColor
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_hoverColor;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (m_hoverColor != value)
                    {
                        m_hoverColor = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            
    
            public override Color BackColor
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_backColor;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (m_backColor != value)
                    {
                        m_backColor = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            public Color SelectedColor
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_selectedColor;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (m_selectedColor != value)
                    {
                        m_selectedColor = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            public Color NotSelectedColor
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_NotSelectedColor;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (m_NotSelectedColor != value)
                    {
                        m_NotSelectedColor = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            public int OutlineThickness
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_outlineThickness;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (m_outlineThickness != value)
                    {
                        m_outlineThickness = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
    
    
            public int HoverStar
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_hoverStar;
                }
            }
    
            public int SelectedStar
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_selectedStar;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (m_selectedStar != value)
                    {
                        m_selectedStar = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
        
    
            #endregion
    
            protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
            {
                pe.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);
    
                int starWidth = (Width - (LeftMargin + RightMargin + (StarSpacing * (StarCount - 1)))) / StarCount;
                int starHeight = (Height - (TopMargin + BottomMargin));
    
                Rectangle drawArea = new Rectangle(LeftMargin, TopMargin, starWidth, starHeight);
    
                for (int i = 0; i < StarCount; ++i)
                {
                    m_starAreas[i].X = drawArea.X - StarSpacing / 2;
                    m_starAreas[i].Y = drawArea.Y;
                    m_starAreas[i].Width = drawArea.Width + StarSpacing / 2;
                    m_starAreas[i].Height = drawArea.Height;
    
                    DrawStar(pe.Graphics, drawArea, i);
    
                    drawArea.X += drawArea.Width + StarSpacing;
                }
    
                base.OnPaint(pe);
            }
    
            protected void DrawStar(Graphics g, Rectangle rect, int starAreaIndex)
            {
                Brush fillBrush;
                Pen outlinePen = new Pen(OutlineColor, OutlineThickness);
    
                if (m_hovering && m_hoverStar > starAreaIndex)
                {
                    fillBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, HoverColor, BackColor, LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal);
                }
                else if ((!m_hovering) && m_selectedStar > starAreaIndex)
                {
                    fillBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, SelectedColor, BackColor, LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal);
                }
                else
                {
                    fillBrush = new SolidBrush(NotSelectedColor);
                }
    
                PointF[] p = new PointF[10];
                p[0].X = rect.X + (rect.Width / 2);
                p[0].Y = rect.Y;
                p[1].X = rect.X + (42 * rect.Width / 64);
                p[1].Y = rect.Y + (19 * rect.Height / 64);
                p[2].X = rect.X + rect.Width;
                p[2].Y = rect.Y + (22 * rect.Height / 64);
                p[3].X = rect.X + (48 * rect.Width / 64);
                p[3].Y = rect.Y + (38 * rect.Height / 64);
                p[4].X = rect.X + (52 * rect.Width / 64);
                p[4].Y = rect.Y + rect.Height;
                p[5].X = rect.X + (rect.Width / 2);
                p[5].Y = rect.Y + (52 * rect.Height / 64);
                p[6].X = rect.X + (12 * rect.Width / 64);
                p[6].Y = rect.Y + rect.Height;
                p[7].X = rect.X + rect.Width / 4;
                p[7].Y = rect.Y + (38 * rect.Height / 64);
                p[8].X = rect.X;
                p[8].Y = rect.Y + (22 * rect.Height / 64);
                p[9].X = rect.X + (22 * rect.Width / 64);
                p[9].Y = rect.Y + (19 * rect.Height / 64);
    
                g.FillPolygon(fillBrush, p);
                g.DrawPolygon(outlinePen, p);
            }
    
            protected override void OnMouseEnter(System.EventArgs ea)
            {
                m_hovering = true;
                Invalidate();
                base.OnMouseEnter(ea);
            }
    
            protected override void OnMouseLeave(System.EventArgs ea)
            {
                m_hovering = false;
                Invalidate();
                base.OnMouseLeave(ea);
            }
    
            protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs args)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < StarCount; ++i)
                {
                    if (m_starAreas[i].Contains(args.X, args.Y))
                    {
                        m_hoverStar = i + 1;
                        Invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                }
    
                base.OnMouseMove(args);
            }
    
            protected override void OnClick(System.EventArgs args)
            {
                Point p = PointToClient(MousePosition);
    
                for (int i = 0; i < StarCount; ++i)
                {
                    if (m_starAreas[i].Contains(p))
                    {
                        m_hoverStar = i + 1;
                        m_selectedStar = i + 1;
                        Invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                }
    
                base.OnClick(args);
            }
    
            #region Protected Data
    
            protected int m_leftMargin = 2;
            protected int m_rightMargin = 2;
            protected int m_topMargin = 2;
            protected int m_bottomMargin = 2;
            protected int m_starSpacing = 8;
        

    protected int m_starCount = 5;
        protected Rectangle[] m_starAreas;
        protected bool m_hovering = false;

        protected int m_hoverStar = 0;
        protected int m_selectedStar = 0;

        protected Color m_outlineColor = Color.DarkGray;
        protected Color m_hoverColor = Color.Yellow;
        protected Color m_selectedColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
        protected Color m_NotSelectedColor = Color.Gray;
        protected Color m_backColor = SystemColors.Control;
        protected int m_outlineThickness = 0;

        #endregion

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
    }
}
```

I tried many solution, but none of them works.
I even try to remove it but I need up removing the stars.

Edited: I added the full code and a picture to make it more clear.
So deleting  the blue color to show my button for ex.
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeO6U.png)

Comment: Still no solution.

Comment: `Color NotSelectedColor = Color.Transparent;` If this doesn't work then there is an error in your hover or selection logic, elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @rfmodulator I just added the full code. NotSelectedColor only represents the unselected stars which is needed, what I don't need is the rectuncle background that surrounds the stars.

Comment: I think you can use the Region property of UserControl to set an irregular shape. You can create a Region with a GraphicsPath. There are lots of samples. You can make a Path with the pixels coordinates of your star.